# How do I convince smartmontools that my SSD is not a hard drive?

Tags: debian, ssd, smart, smartctl, smartmontools

I'm running Debian Wheezy, stock `smartmontools` package (smartctl 5.41).

An SSD, Mushkin `MKNSSDCR120GB-MX`, is reporting usage lifetime information in SMART attribute id 231 (decimal). For hard drives this attribute is `Temperature_Celsius`, and unfortunately smartmontools is interpreting it as such:

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
[...]
231 Temperature_Celsius     0x0013   001   001   010    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 21474836481
[...]
```

No, not 21 billion degrees Celsius ... it is supposed to be an indication of the [SSD life left](https://serverfault.com/a/439474/116955).

I tried updating the drive database using the command:

```
# /usr/sbin/update-smart-drivedb
/usr/share/smartmontools/drivedb.h updated from branches/RELEASE_5_41_DRIVEDB
#
```

... and restarting `smartd`, but the drive is still not recognized as an SSD.

Is there a solution other than adding the backports repo and installing the `smartmontools` backports version? If I have to do this, then I will, but I currently don't have any backports software on this server and it seems like there must be another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run update-smart-drivedb it downloads the most recent database from the source site for smartmontools, in theory more recent than any backport.

You should get a reasonable turn around time if you contact them directly ..

From https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki ...

> Device Information
>
> If your drive is not in the ​current version of smartmontools drive
>   database you can help to improve smartmontools information by sending
>   a report about your drive to our mailinglist ​smartmontools-database.
>
> We collect info about USB devices that have been successfully or
>   unsuccessfully tested with smartmontools. If you have a device not
>   listed there, please tell us the test result, by editing the wiki
>   page, and/or by sending an email to the ​smartmontools-database
>   mailinglist.